# IE8 html select needs two clicks to open dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#click").dblclick(function(e) {
            var options = "<select id='combobox'>"
            for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                options += '<option value="ActionScript">Value - ' + i + '</option>';
            }
            $(this).html(options + "</select>");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="click">double click me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After double clicking on `div`, a `select` element is rendered in the `div`. The problem is in IE8 after `select` is rendered, it needs two clicks to open the dropdown menu. It should be opened in a single click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found this solution. I have use jQuery `appendTo` as in `$(options + "</select>").appendTo(this);` method instead of `.html` as in `$(this).html(options + "</select>");` .

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I don't have an IE8 Please try to add `$('#click').unbind('dblclick');` after create select element, it will dissable #click dblclick event.

```
$(function() {
     $("#click").dblclick(function(e) {
          var options = "<select id='combobox'>"
          for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
               options += '<option value="ActionScript">Value - ' + i + '</option>';
          }

          $(this).html(options + "</select>");
          $('#click').unbind('dblclick');
     });
});
```

Comment: Are you using IE8 mode of IE9?