# jQuery appendTo vs html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had a problem, mentioned here [IE8 html select needs two clicks to open dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15571059/1823389). I fixed it by replacing jQuery `.html(...)` with `appendTo`. Anyone knows why it happened?

***Summary of the problem*** -

The issue was when we insert an HTML `select` using `innerHTML/jQuery.html(...)` into some other HTML element(`div` or `span`) which has a click or double click listener attached to it,  Clicking on select reuqired two clicks to open the dropdown in IE8. I was using `jQuery.html(…)` method, which I replaced with `jQuery.appendTo(...)` method and it worked fine. I still don’t know why there is problem using innerHTML/jQuery.html() in my case.

Comment: I tested your original code from your original question in my IE8 on WinXP and it works fine, double click the div and single click the select to drop down.  Having said that, IE pops up a context menu button sometimes (live search etc etc) if I double click the TEXT and not the empty part of the div - could that be your problem?

Comment: No, I have disabled that IE8 context menu from IE options, still I was getting the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 html select needs two clicks to open dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571059/ie8-html-select-needs-two-clicks-to-open-dropdown)

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the Web Accelerator in IE8.

In your example, when double-clicking the DIV, `.html()` replaces the innerHTML, but combobox is still selected.
(If use `.appendTo()`, text is selected, not the combobox). 
In Web Accelerator mode, the first click on the combobox will work as focus (an IE8 bug?).

So, to fix this bug, you can clear the selection after double click.

```
$(function() {

    $("#click").dblclick(function(e) {
        clearSelection();// clear selection
        var options = "<select id='combobox'>"
        for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            options += '<option value="ActionScript">Value - ' + i + '</option>';
        }
        $(this).html(options + "</select>");
    });
});

function clearSelection() {
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the if i disable IE 8 Web Accelerator from tools, my code would work?

Comment: Yes, you can disable it from Internet Option. But remember your user will not do this.

Comment: yes, I already have tried it, but it doesnt work

Comment: It works for me (ie8.0.7601.17514 64-bit edition). You had tried both? selection clear & disable Web Accelerator .

Answer (score 0):

appendTo will add to existing DOM element , but .html will replace the all elements inside the DOM element

Comment: This is not reason why `appendTo` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` is work like replace html inside dom. So using `.html()` will erase you `DOM` element and `replace` it with new so new `element` and that `elements` might not have event assigned to it as long as you did not used `delegate` or `.on`.

`.appendTo()` is work as adding child to `DOM` so other `DOM` element still have event that is assigned before. But if i am not wrong your newly loaded `DOM` element still does not have `events` assigned to them.

So you can use `.on()`;

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not the problem I solved using `appendTo`. Please visit the link mentioned in the problem statement

Comment: @MoazzamKhan already did and tested but selectbox option visiable on first click

Comment: In my problem, I am not attaching any event to `select`, so using `.on(...)` is not required. I summarized the issue in problem statement.