# ie 8 need click twice for input field how to resolve it

Tags: javascript, java, browser

i am don't want to click twice in input field, because of DOCTYPE tag inside html page in IFRAME structure ie need twice click and if i remove DOCTYPE then my page design gets changed

Answer (score 0):

It is Microsoft issue, You would need to install latest security patch to resolve this:
see this [see this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/3052190)

See if this [Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571059/ie8-html-select-needs-two-clicks-to-open-dropdown) Solution works for you.

Comment: I have already given link (which is other way to solve this).